# Is it allowed to cross in between two persons offering namaz?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, behavior

After jumuah prayer, people were performing nafl. I tried to move out of masjid so I walked in between two persons who offering namaz.

But one of those persons pushed me; I was unable to go back also.  Later while one of them was performing sujud, I crossed in between them.  After some time, this incident hurting me a lot; I fear a lot.  Is it allowed to cross in between two persons offering namaz, or I did commit a big sin?

Comment: When you crossed in front of them, would there have been enough space if they made sujood from the place where you crossed?

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate, there is similar question with an answer that is relevant to your question:

[Crossing while someone is praying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/crossing-while-someone-is-praying)

What you did is not a sin, unless you intentionally tried to distract them, or knowingly.

It is odd these days that people don't get disturbed by loud gossip and laughter outside the masjid, but they're distracted by people who are quietly and innocently trying to leave after finishing their salat.

We have people who pray while the Imam of masjid is giving Khutbah, yet they don't get disturbed by it, they must have some incredibly high level of concentration to not get distracted by the Imam speaking on a loud speaker.

but some of these same people who pray during Khubah, complain when someone walks in front of them. It is hypocrisy and ignorance that leads to such none sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, what your asking as to whether you crossed in between them or crossed from ahead/in front of them.

If I'm right in thinking it as the second one, then..

What the **first person** did is according to this...

> The Messenger of Allah said: Pray facing a [sutrah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutrah), and let no one cross in front of you while praying. If he insists, then prevent him by force because he is accompanied by shaitan. (Sahih Ibn Khuzaimah, Chapter: Salat, Hadith No. 793)

And what the **second person** made a mistake is he failed to follow this...

> Sahl ibn Abu Hathmah narrated: The Prophet said: When one of you prays facing a sutrah he should keep close to it, and not let the devil interrupt his prayer. (Sunan Abu Dawud :: Book 2 : Hadith 695)

So, if you ask me like any other sin, while we'll be doing the sin, the devil will be accompanying us most of the time. So, as the general rule says,

> Allah accepts only the repentance of those who do evil in ignorance and foolishness and repent soon afterwards; it is they to whom Allah will forgive and Allah is Ever All-Knower, All-Wise. (Qur'an 4:17)

So, it is suggested that, you ask forgiveness from God, as soon as possible in the best way you can. And try not to do it again.

May the creator guide us all.