# Someone passes in front of me while i was praying in congregation. Am I responsible for it?

Tags: salat, masjid, jamaat

On Friday I missed one rakat and after imam salam I continued my prayer but someone passes in front of me while i was praying.
Am i responsible for the sin or the person who passes in front of me

If I am responsible what should I do now

Is there any kaffarah for me?

*Please Answer*

Comment: This question will help you: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/is-crossing-someone-while-he-is-praying-permissible?rq=1

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please specify and elaborate what you mean by "pass in front of me": At what distance? Would you be able to perform sujud without any difficulty? Would you be able to stop him without moving a step forward? There's no kaffarah that I know of. But the person passing in front of you is committing a huge sin especially if he does so intentionally.

Answer (score -1):

As long as they pass in front of you at a respectful distance and they do not disturb you doing namaz then there is no kaffarah.

It's often happened to me when at the mosque whilst doing the non-obligatory prayers when people move to other parts of the mosque to pray; and I've also observed it happening to others there with no one raising any kind of objection or commotion.

Why did you think otherwise?

**edit**

@Medi1Saif: I find that difficult to believe. Do you have an authentic hadith regarding this?

Comment: There are ahadith telling you that such a person is a Satan and ask you to fight him. I've been once rudely notified by a neighbor of a praying person however in the crowd I was unable to distinguish praying from not praying people. So it seems in the mosque you frequent people are either unaware of the sunnah of passive.

Comment: Of course it is among the most authentic narrations as it appears in both sahihs https://sunnah.com/bulugh/2 and it is mentioned in the answer linked in the comment above. May Allah forgive your ignorance.